# Run every pytest test function simultaneously with another function

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, python-multithreading

I want every pytest test run simultaneously with a function recording video. I want to somehow make pytest do something like this

test_function1
test_function2
test_function

When pytest would call every function for execution it would couple it with record_video(). Like test_function{n} + record_video()

In the end it woud return a report on how the test was executed and a .mp4 file with a recording.

How to achieve that? I guess it should be possible somehow

Comment: You can add it in the setup method of your tests - the setup runs before every test function.

Comment: @TDG Thank you for suggestion! I didn't know I could do it this way. Please, could you share an example as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html) are a perfect use case for this.

See the following hypothetical example --

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def record_video():
    record.start()
    yield
    record.stop()


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def generate_report():
    yield
    report.make()
```

Comment: It's something so simple and yet ingenious haha Thank you so much!